# Deleting items from UITableView (without removing them)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a rather simple UITableView with exactly 20 items (the size of their inventory in a game.) My custom table cell is smart enough to display "SLOT EMPTY" text for cells that represent inventory slots that don't contain items. I have a working solution, but wanted to know if there was a better way to handle it.

**Intended result**

The user's inventory might look like this:

```
Bellybutton fuzz
Petrified weasel snout
Chocolate covered toilet seat
Coupon for a high-five from Chase
SLOT 5 EMPTY
SLOT 6 EMPTY
.
.
.
SLOT 20 EMPTY
```

If the user deletes the toilet seat then the list should look like this:

```
Bellybutton fuzz
Petrified weasel snout
Coupon for a high-five from Chase
SLOT 4 EMPTY
SLOT 5 EMPTY
.
.
.
SLOT 20 EMPTY
```

Note that the list still contains 20 cells after deletion with the used cells shifted up to occupy the top three slots of the inventory.

**The problem**

My initial attempt was to use was to use `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]` and adjust my backing data to reflect the new content (one less inventory item, one additional empty slot.) However, this crashed with the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows
contained in an existing section after the update (20) must be equal to the number
of rows contained in that section before the update (20), plus or minus the number
of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or
minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

**The solution (?)**

[Note that the code in this section is heavily simplified from actual code for clarity - the question is about the solution technique, not the specific implementation details.]

What I came up with in the end feels like a bit of a hack to me, but does produce the intended result.

Deleting an item looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        NSDictionary *item = [self itemForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!item) return;

        // Keep track of the deleted item count
        self.mDeletedEntries += 1;

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [tableView endUpdates];

        // Remove it from the data store
        [Inventory removeInventoryItem:item];
    }
}
```

Then later, I replace the missing items:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // If we have deleted some entries and need to add some new ones, schedule
    // a process to insert them.
    //
    // *This is what feels like a hack to me*
    if (self.mDeletedEntries)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(addEmptySlots:) withObject:tableView afterDelay:0];
    }

    // Return the current count that IOS wants (inventory size minus the deleted ones)
    return kUserMaxInventorySize - self.mDeletedEntries;
}

- (void)addEmptySlots:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // We start adding entries into the list at the end
    int insertLocation = kUserMaxInventorySize - self.mDeletedEntries;

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    // Add the deleted entries (should only ever be 1 entry, really)    
    for (int i = 0; i < self.mDeletedEntries; ++i)
    {
        // They get added to the end of the table
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertLocation + i inSection:0];
        NSArray *indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path,nil];

        // Insert the entry. We don't need to actually add the item to our data store,
        // since empty entries will simply report "Slot empty" text.
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    }

    // These are no longer deleted
    self.mDeletedEntries = 0;

    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

This works, but the is this the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think I'd just update the table's backing data and reloadData -- don't bother with deleting cells.

Comment: How about a simple NSMutableArray with 20 NSString objects containing `SLOT %d EMPTY` initially, then start replacing the objects with your real objects. On deletion, replace it with a string again.

Comment: @HotLicks The problem with the reloadData is that you lose the ability to animate the item off of the list. I had many other issues with this as well, including some EXTREMELY odd results from the cells moving to the top of the table and running an bouncing animation behind the cell that was already at the top. Very strange stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach makes this more complicated than it has to be. For example, you said your tableview will always have exactly 20 cells. Why doesn't `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section' simply return 20?

I'm not really sure how you are storing the items in your inventory. I'm just going write my examples as though you have an NSMutableArray named inventory.

I would simply always return 20 as the number of rows.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check to see if an item exists the row you are creating a cell for or if you should create an "SLOT EMPTY" cell:

```
– tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    if ( [indexPath row] < [inventory count] ) {
        // configure a cell that represents actual inventory
        NSDictionary *item = [inventory objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        ...
    } else {
        // configure a "SLOT * EMPTY" cell
        NSUInteger slotNumber = [indexPath row] - [inventory count] + 1;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

When you delete an item remove it from your array, delete the row, and add a row at the bottom of your tableview to take it's place:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // Remove it from the data store
        [inventory removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        // you also need to insert a row at the bottom so the number of rows is correct
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:19 inSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! You are absolutely right - I simply hadn't thought to insert the entries during the update process that removed the inventory items. The trick in my case was to insert the new entry immediately after the last actual inventory item (post-deletion) and not at the end of the list. However that's implementation specific.